# C# Merge two header columns into one column?

Tags: c#

I use C#[2013] winform. I drag and drop a datagridview and design it in two cols then I select value from database to it. I now want to merge two headers into one only. The headers already displayed by designing in properties.
I want to merge the columns.

```
Col1   |  Col2 

001    |  John
```

I want to merge into one col as

```
  Title

  001    |   John
```

How to merge it?

Comment: show us your code on what youre actually doing, how youre getting the data and we might just be able to help you

Comment: The question os not clear enough. Do you also want to merge the actual content of the columns or only the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a DataGridView, there doesn't appear to be an easy built in-solution for this. Perhaps you could simply copy the data from one column to the other and split them with some sort of delimiter (perhaps a comma).

Modify then run following code after you fill your grid with data:

```
string data = string.Empty;
int indexCol0 = 0;
int indexCol1 = 1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   row.Cells[indexCol0].Value = row.Cells[indexCol0].Value + ", " + row.Cells[indexCol1].Value;
dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(indexCol1);
```

Comment: No, May be I make bad question, because of my English.  Col1 and Col2 is a table. I need to merge the columns into one column, but the cells still keep in two cells. Just merge the header.

Comment: Are we talking about the database side? Any reason you can't use a view to achieve this? Why must they absolutely be in the separate columns, why can't you use a delimiter and work with that logic?

Comment: No, No, all these don't work in my needed. I have a datagrid with few columns ex: Col_ID,Col_firstName, Col_lastname, Datebirth, Depertment.... I want all the cells keep in the same design but Col_firstName and Col_lastName I need to change to only a Col called Full_Name. In the Full_Name columns has two cell like cell first_name and cell Last_name. Just want to split the line between Col_firstname and Col_lastname.

Answer (score 3):

What type of datasource are you binding to...  You might just be better to add a new column to a datatable, or property to a class/structure that is a combined value of the two in question.  Then just display that one.

If editing is done to any individual field, then update the JOINED column/property as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the class that you are using as the source for you `DataGridView` put a new property:

```
public string Title { get { return this.Col1 + " | " + this.Col2; }}
```

then delete those two columns and add one column for `Title`